# What would you store in the DB, Coordinates or Address?

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, coordinates, geocoding, street-address

I am building an application that uses the GMaps API v3 and, taking advantage of the geocoding function, i dont know if it is better to store in the DB:

1. The coordinates (latitude & longitude)

   - When i need to place a marker, just put it
   - When i need the address, query the API
2. The address (as a string)

   - When i need to place a marker, query the API
   - When i need to post the address, just print it
3. Store Both

What would you recommend?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i would advice you to store both, at least,just image how many request and wood you save.I would even say you beter have your own local geoDB, when google is down you don´t care :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recommend:

**1) Storing both**

2) Cranberry and Mint Martini. (excellent vodka drink, take after success in programming).

Comment: ok... i store both. Cranberry and mint martini? i always say that the best amount of alcohol for programming is 1 and a half biers